# jQuery Ajax data to same PHP page not working as INTENDED?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 22.php that both form and PHP script reside.

Problems;

[image: Before submit screenshot]

[image: After submit screenshot]

1) when I submit, result shows below. But duplicates the form.

2) Further entering in the top (above) form, changes the result accordingly.

3) When I enter in the bottom form, then also the result changes accordingly and disappear the bottom from.

What I have tried so far as solutions;

1) removed totally -  url: '',

2) replaced to the same page -  url: '22.php',

3) replaced to this -   var yourData = $(this).serialize();

4) Placed the PHP script just soon after body tag

None of above solve! Please help!

```html
<html>    
    <head>
      <title>My first PHP page</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" 
         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {            
        $("#btn").click(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
          
      var myname = $("#name").val();
        var myage = $("#age").val();
            var yourData ='name='+myname+'&age='+myage; // php is expecting name and age
            $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
     data:yourData,//Without serialized                
              //url: '22.php',
              success:function(data) {
                 if(data){
                    $('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form
           $('#result').html(data); // here html()
                    //alert('Submitted');
                 }else{
                    return false;
                  }                        
               }
             });
             
            });             
         });
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>

<?php
if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) { // was the form submitted?
    echo "Welcome ". $_POST["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "You are ". $_POST["age"] . "years old<br>";
}
?>
 
      <form method="post" id="testform">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />Age:
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" />
      </form>
 <div id='result'></div>
 

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place PHP code top and put exit();. Here is your full code:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) { // was the form submitted?
    echo "Welcome ". $_POST["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "You are ". $_POST["age"] . "years old<br>";
    exit;
}
?>
<html>    
    <head>
      <title>My first PHP page</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" 
         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {            
        $("#btn").click(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();

            var myname = $("#name").val();
            var myage = $("#age").val();
            var yourData ='name='+myname+'&age='+myage; // php is expecting name and age
            $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              data:yourData,//Without serialized                
              //url: '22.php',
              success:function(data) {
                 if(data){
                    $('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form
                    $('#result').html(data); // here html()
                    //alert('Submitted');
                 }else{
                    return false;
                  }                        
               }
             });

            });             
         });
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>

  <form method="post" id="testform">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />Age:
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" />
  </form>
  <div id='result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That solved my problem. But please give me a brief explanation why we do so? Thanks

Comment: OK..the problem was ajax request action url. You were giving the same page url i.e. 22.php in action and 22.php is contained your html form code so in ajax response you were getting whole the page (22.php) content. So i have just exit the execution of whole file when executing ajax request.